# .htaccess mod_rewrite remap without redirection?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following to redirect http://example.com/somedir/?_escaped_fragment=key=val to http://example.com/somedir/static/?key=val.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}static/?%1 [L,R=302]
```

How can I hide the URL change? I'd like to avoid using mod_proxy, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the **,R=302** for an **internal** redirect, see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html