# Subdomain redirect from https to http doesn't work

Tags: regex, virtualhost, apache2.4

I want rewrite link at apache. Apache work with ssl. And my application return some requests as https link. Example:

https://www-prd.euro1.sdl.electric.com/uk/en/assets-re1/js/adapt-img.js

needs to be redirected to:

http://www-prd.euro1.sdl.electric.com/uk/en/assets-re1/js/adapt-img.js

Just replace https on http.
My last variant:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://electric\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://electric.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But this not help me.

Config file:

```
ProxyPass /server-status !
Listen 443
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
Mutex default
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXP:!LOW:!RC2:!3DES:!SEED:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.key

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName fe1-app.projects.com
SSLEngine on
AllowEncodedSlashes On
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://www-prd\.euro1\.sdl\.electric\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www-prd.euro1.sdl.electric.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>

ProxyPassMatch  (.*) http://localhost:20180 nocanon
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyStatus On
SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 0
```

Comment: So apache have ssl (http`s`), but you need to redirect to link without ssl (http)? It's confusing

Comment: Yes, redirect without ssl(https) for some URLs.

Comment: some? What the rule then?

Comment: The rule should rewrite link " https: www-prd.euro1.sdl.electric.com/uk/en/assets-re1/js/adapt-img.js" to  "http www-prd.euro1.sdl.electric.com/uk/en/assets-re1/js/adapt-img.js"

Comment: I mean what is url pattern for redirect? If only the one you mentioned, then:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https:www-prd\.euro1\.sdl\.electric\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:www-prd.euro1.sdl.electric.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it didn't help. I attached config file

Comment: remove extra space after `https: ` and `http: `

Comment: I just deleted double pipe //, because  stackoverflow don't show http and https. Example with https -  https://www-prd.euro1.sdl.electric.com

Comment: Your `ServerName` is fe1-app.projects.com, yet the domain you want to redirect is www-prd.euro1.sdl.electric.com ?!?  You say `But this not help me.`, what happens?  Logs?  Did you look at the return in the browser console?  Do you get a 301?

Comment: My application after apache has html with <script type="text/javascript" src="//www-prd.euro1.sdl.electric.com/bla/bla/bla/js.js"></script>. I trying do config with ssl. I see In browser that all GET requests has https now, instead http. I don't get 301. Logs without errors and some information about redirect. I have in config `code` RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https: www-prd\.euro1\.sdl\.electric\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http: www-prd.euro1.sdl.electric.com/$1 [L,R=301] `code`. fe1-app.projects.com - apache server.

Comment: So you need that script that requested via url 

`https://www-prd.euro1.sdl.electric.com/bla/bla/bla/js.js` to be loaded (not redirected) from

`http://www-prd.euro1.sdl.electric.com/bla/bla/bla/js.js`
right? Are you able to open script url in browser by https or http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://` should not prefix `HTTP_HOST`, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www-prd\.euro1\.sdl\.electric\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www-prd.euro1.sdl.electric.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you need js just to be loaded (no redirect) try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www-prd\.euro1\.sdl\.electric\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www-prd.euro1.sdl.electric.com/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I able open scripts by http, https links don't work.. Browser In debug has rows Loading failed for the <script> with source “[link](https://www-prd.euro1.sdl.electric.com/uk/en/assets-re1/js/adapt-img.js)”. Js should load from http address.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649101/htaccess-mod-rewrite-remap-without-redirection then it's probably the same